# How to prove this property using SVD decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to show the following property: Let $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ with $n\leq m$. If $\|A^TA-I\|_2=\gamma<1$ show that $\sigma_{\min}(A)\geq 1-\gamma$ where $\sigma_{\min}(A)$ is the least singular value of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A = U_{m \times m} \Sigma_{m \times n} V^T_{n \times n}$ be the full SVD decomposition. We then have
$$A^TA = V \Sigma^T \Sigma V^T \implies A^TA - I = V (\Sigma^T \Sigma -I)V^T$$
Hence,
$$\gamma = \Vert A^TA - I \Vert_2 = \Vert V (\Sigma^T \Sigma -I)V^T \Vert_2 = \Vert \Sigma^T \Sigma - I \Vert_2$$
where we have used the fact that if $Q$ is a unitary matrix then
$$\Vert QX \Vert_2 = \Vert X \Vert_2$$
Hence, we have
$$\vert \sigma_i^2 - 1 \vert \leq \gamma \implies 1-\gamma \leq \sigma_i^2 \leq 1 + \gamma \,\,\,\,\, \forall i$$

Comment: thanks for the help, cool solution =D